# How to disable SSL verification using Qt and Python?

Tags: python, ssl, pyqt

I use `Python` and `Qt` to request `https://some-site.com` like this:

```
def init_request(self):  
    req = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl('https://some-site.com'))    
    self.nam = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
    self.nam.finished.connect(self.handle_response)        
    self.nam.get(req)
    
def handle_response(self, reply): 
    if reply.error() != QtNetwork.QNetworkReply.NoError:
        print(reply.errorString())
        return
```

`print(reply.errorString())` outputs `SSL handshake failed` because the `https://some-site.com` has problem with SSL certificate.

I know, it is possible to insecure connect to the server using `curl`:

```
curl --insecure https://some-site.com
```

How to do the same connect with `Python` and `Qt`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `QNetworkReply.ignoreSslErrors()` like this.

```
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtNetwork import *

app = QApplication()

net_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl('https://www.google.com'))
reply = net_manager.get(request)
reply.ignoreSslErrors()
def on_finish():
    print([reply.error(), reply.attribute(QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute)])
    app.quit()
reply.finished.connect(on_finish);

app.exec_()
```

Also, you can increase security by limiting error types and certificates with `ignoreSslErrors(errors)`. Refer to [the reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkreply.html#ignoreSslErrors-1).